# /etc/environment changes reload immediatly in Ubuntu 16.04 but not in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, server, environment-variables

I noticed that changing the content of `/etc/environment` in Ubuntu 16.04.1 immediately updates the output of `env` while doing this in Ubuntu 14.04.4 doesn't update the output of `env` (which requires you to reboot/login for the changes to take effect).

I couldn't find any information on this change when I searched the Internet. Does anyone know more about how this change was implemented? And, is there a way to let Ubuntu 14.04 behave like 16.04?

Update:
The exact steps I take are:

```
sudo vim /etc/environment
*add or remove a line*
sudo env
*check whether the line is added or removed*
```

Comment: Can you summarize the exact steps you are taking to change the contents and to test the `env` output? I am unable to reproduce this behavior

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: What you are describing only applies to the environment of processes run using `sudo`, I think - and is a result of differences in the `/etc/pam.d/sudo` configuration files. See [sudo not setting environment variables in /etc/environment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1301557)

Comment: I checked the `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file on both systems, but their appears to be no difference. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure about that? Comparing 14.04 and 16.04 systems of my own, one has `auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1` while the other has `session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1` (note `auth` versus `session`)

Comment: @steeldriver Well spotted, they do differ like that at my systems as well! Sorry for missing that the first time. Changing auth to session on that line fixed it! Could you add this as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `/etc/pam.d/sudo` (e.g., `sudo vim /etc/pam.d/sudo`) and change `auth` to `session` at the start of the following line:

```
auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
```

So it should become:

```
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
```